# Custom API Gateway vs Reverse-proxy products

Tags: api-gateway, envoyproxy

I am trying to understand the main difference between

(1) Using a reverse-proxy such as Nginx or Envoy as a gateway to route requests to corresponding microservice

vs

(2) Building a custom solution which uses the HttpClient (in .Net) to forward the request to the corresponding microservice. I would like to understand the benefits and drawbacks of each approach.

I think that the first approach Layer 7 routing, is that mean it is more performant than the second.

Comment: Why do you want to develop a custom solution if there is one that is tested and proven to be working? Added advantage of customization and configuration options make this more preferable over custom solution

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [wander3r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694593/wander3r). I'm using [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) currently as my API proxy. With envoy, it's not only act as proxy but also handle logging, load balancing, rate limiting, circuit breaking etc.

If you are new to envoy. i did a simple step by step guide on how to start using envoy proxy.

[Envoy Proxy Guide](https://github.com/M457ERCH1EF/Envoy-Proxy-Guide)